# Multicore Mp3 encoder for OSX, is it available? Why not?

Tags: mp3, encoding, logic-pro

Hi Everyone,

Not necessarilly a sound design question..
Everyone probably runs a multicore computer and since we are in the business of sound, we need to create a lot of mp3 files. Now this is something that has been available for years but and I don't want to think about the cummulated hours I've waited for mp3 conversions.

With the advent of faster cpu's encoding jumped down to a few minutes for long files.
But still I find myself waiting for mp3 encodes more than I want to.

Today i noticed that Logics' mp3 encoder only utilises 1 core in my cpu (i5), why?

Does anyone know a software package/codec that's available for pro tools and logic, that allows for multicore encoding on a mac?

Ps. Just to be clear. I'm not looking for a batch converter that utilises multiple cores, i want a codec that utilises them.

Comment: hi tim, why did you erase the multicore and i5 tag?

Answer (score 2):

Max uses many threads so it can encode an mp3 on single and each core.

http://sbooth.org/Max/

Comment: thanks. strange, i've been using max for over a year on my daw and it never uses more than 1 core. just opened it up on my 2006 macbook running SL and now it uses both cores? same version of max different os. i'll need to look into this.. 

Answer (score 1):

lame does high quality MP3 using multicore, it's on the command line and so is naturally scriptable. just make sure you grab a recent version.

Comment: thanks, i found a lame version 3.99 but it doesn't work in logic. the command line is a last resort, i don't like using command lines, so maybe i'll try an applescript or something..

Comment: "we need to create a lot of mp3 files" ... render to wav then batch convert? 

Answer (score -1):

Try Switch from NCH.com.au

regards
Mark